# How can I mimic the color saturation of Nikon's miniature-faking mode?

Tags: post-processing, white-balance, reverse-engineering, saturation, tone-curves

Nikon's on-camera "miniature faking" tweak appears to increase the saturation, increase the contrast, and perform some selective horizontal/vertical blurring (with a falloff region) for a tilt-shift effect.

There are more robust solutions for mimicking the tilt-shift DoF than the one available through this filter, so I would rather use those. But, I can't quite replicate the saturation and contrast effects on my end.

Here's an example; Original on the left and "mini faked" on the right. Click to expand images.

[image: original image]
[image: miniature faking]

What process needs to be done to mimc the contrast and color saturation portions of this filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There also appears to be either a color temperature shift towards amber/yellow as well as a [white balance "correction](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/104336/15871)" towards green, or a strong yellow color cast introduced by boosting the orange/yellow bands more than the other colors such as can be done with an [Hue-Saturation-Luminance (HSL) tool](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/102438/15871). Some raw processing applications call such a tool HSB or HSV (the last letter is for 'brightness' or 'value' instead of 'luminance', which are all interchangeable in this context).

Such tools allow one to adjust the hue, saturation, and luminance (brightness) of each of eight color bands independently of one another. Most tools divide the color wheel into Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Aqua, Blue, Purple, and Magenta bands.